# Monitor bean injection failure

Tags: java, spring

we have an application with spring beans (3 levels) running on tomcat, the beans are annotated with `@Autowired` and are mandatory.

What we would like to do is monitor bean injection failure (which can indicate a deployment problem).

The way I'm thinking I have two options to do so:

1. Instead of using `@Autowired` load the beans in a static block, if
   the load fails *do something*
2. Surround code with `try{...} catch (NullPointerException e)`, so if the bean is `null` the exception is thrown.
3. Check if the beans equal `null` at every method.

I think #1 is the most elegant and with the least amount of code to add, but I am wondering whether there is an elegant way to do this without a static block.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quiet a few options here.
My favorite is to annotate required dependency with `@Autowired(required=false)` and then in method anotated with `@PostConstruct` test and handle missing dependency:

```
...
@Autowired(required = false)
private Bean dependency;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
  if(dependency==null) {
     // handle missing dependecy
  }
}
```

There is quiet interesting article about checking of required dendecies in Spring. It's a bit older but still beneficilal.
http://blog.springsource.org/2007/07/11/setter-injection-versus-constructor-injection-and-the-use-of-required/

Answer (score 2):

i think u need `@Autowired(required=true)`

Also, `required` is true by default. So any missing dependency will raise an alert.
See [@AutoWired](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)

Comment: required is true by default, and it will throw BeanCreationException in case no matching definition found

Comment: yes you are right...i was updating the same in answer with proper link

Comment: So I just need to try/catch BeanCreationException?

Comment: @SigalShaharabani No, u don't need to. Only keeping `@Autowired` will work as your application will not deploy in case of missing dependency. This itself is sufficient. You don't need to do any other special handling.

Comment: @Kshitij but the issue here is that we'd like to monitor these failures (we need to send SNMP traps when they occur). Can I do that without catching the exception?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use setter injection and test if the bean is null when it is injected.